# datetime isoformat() what is the integer at the end?

Tags: python, datetime

When I run this piece of code in python :

```
print datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat()
```

I get the following:

```
2016-05-13T18:21:29.484000
```

What is the integer at the end? (484000)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat

Comment: This doesn't say what it is... Also there is no [sep] value in the paranthesis...

Comment: It says that it is not shown if microseconds is 0, I think this gives a good hint...

Comment: Oh ok I get it. Thank you @Dijzeus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microseconds.

See Python docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat